# PHP Query a table column based on value from another column in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]I have a database I have to query using PHP. There are 3 different columns I'm dealing with. What I have to do require a handful of steps so I'll list the steps 1 by 1......
1) I have to go through each value in the 'nid' column. However, some of the 'nids' have duplicate value. Therefore I have to choose the 'nid' with the highest 'vid' value.
2) Once I select the 'nid' with the highest 'vid' value I then have to get the value of the 'title' column that's in the same row of the highest 'vid'. For example if I have a 'vid' of 1253 I have to select the content that's in column title that corresponds with 'vid' 1253. 
I have a lot of the steps. However, I'm getting stuck on once I grab the highest vid, being able to grab the content in the title column. Below is my code

```
<?php
    // Establish all database credential variables
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $databaseName = "redesign_static";
    // Create Database Connection
    $connection = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $databaseName);
    // Check Database Connection
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:" . $connection->connect_error);
    } // line ends if statement
    $queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, vid, title FROM node_revision";
    // line above creates variable $queryNodeRevision > selects column "nid" from table "node_revision"
    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision) or die("Bad Query: $results");
    // line above creates variable $results > actually queries that database and passes in variable "$queryNodeRevision"
    $storeNIDAndVIDValues = []; // empty array to store max 'vid' values

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8000; $i++) {
      $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$i] = 0;
      // line above assigns initial 'vid'; starts at 0
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      $currentNID = $row['nid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current 'nid' of row (aka the key)
      $currentVID = $row['vid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current value of the 'vid' (the number you want to compare)
    if ($currentVID > $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$currentNID]) {
        // if the value of'$currentVID' is greater than what's stored in array '$storeNIDAndVIDValues' at current nid position
        // $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$currentNID] = goes into array $storeNIDAndVIDValues and gets the value of nid key (in this case value represents what position the nid is at)
           $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$currentNID] = $currentVID;
           // line above > becomes max 'vid' at that time 
           $titleOfSelectedVID = $row['title'];
          // $row['title'] = gets the value of the current 'title'
        $queryTitle = "SELECT title FROM node_revision WHERE $currentVID ";
        // line above is query variable that targets 'title' column row that has highest 'vid' value
     } // line ends if statement
    } // line closes while loop
  ?>

$queryTitle = "SELECT title FROM node_revision WHERE
```

The $queryTitle line is where I'm getting stuck. This is where I want to get the content of title column but only the title that corresponds with the highest vid.

Comment: I think you can just do that on a single query like `SELECT nid,vid,title FROM test ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1;` this will display a single record from the highest `vid`

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac So are you saying I can use that 1 line to substitute all the code I wrote or just for the " $queryTitle = "SELECT title FROM node_revision WHERE $currentVID "; "

Comment: You already have title in your original query, so you shouldn't have to query again. In your while loop, write to an array where the key is nid and, if the value of the row's vid is higher than the highest previous vid, set the title value in the array to $row['title']. So you'd write array(nid => title), but you only update that array if the vid is higher in value than any previous vid for that nid.

Comment: @Kerri Do you mean like this? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
          $currentNID = $row['nid'];
          $currentVID = $row['vid']
        if ($currentVID > $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$currentNID]) {
   $theVIDTitleIWant = $row['title']
               $storeNIDAndVIDValues[$currentNID] = $currentVID;
        } // line ends if statement
        } // line closes while loop

Comment: @Aishah91 : yeah, you can use a single query to achieve the same result, In my example, It will always return a single record base from the highest `vid`. Pretty simple right?

Answer (score 0):

Try write query as below

```
SELECT a.* FROM node_revision as a INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(vid) as vid, nid FROM node_revision GROUP BY nid) as b on a.nid = b.nid WHERE a.vid = b.vid
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will this code select the max vid of only the nids that have more than 1 of the same value.

Comment: I have 1 more question. Is it safe to say the > SELECT nid,MAX(vid) as vid,title FROM node_revision GROUP BY nid   reads as...... Select the columns nid, the max of column vid as the value of vid and the column title from table node_revision and group by the nid.

Comment: I edited my comment. This will help you get the exact title of the highest vid

Comment: Thank you but this new line seems very advanced for my level. I want to be able to comprehend it. Will the initial line of code you sent work?

Comment: With the initial line, the title is not correct. However, it will get the highest vid of nid correctly. If you want to use it,  then you have to use loop for the result and write query in loop.

Comment: Ok I see and in regards to the title will the initial line get me the content of the title that corresponds with the vid that has the highest id?

Comment: No, you need write another query in loop.